# Trying to Understand Ripple's Ledger

Tags: blockchain, ripple

I am trying to make sense of Ripple's ledger.

My question:  Is there one ledger, known as the Consensus Ledger, or are there two ledgers: known as Conensus ledger and Validation ledger?

Context:  I was reading about the ledger on Ripple's site.  I understand that transactions first go through a consensus phase and then go through a validation phase. Is each phase its own ledger?

Comment: Wait, should I not ask this question since it is not Bitcoin-related?